# $index in ng-repeat not updated after delete

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, indexing

### Situation

On the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1j1IG.jpg) you can see what I'm trying to to. Using an `ng-repeat` to dynamically add a row of inputfields when `+step` is clicked.  The `x` removes a step and the `up and down arrows` move a step one place up or down.
I want the up arrow to be disabled when a step can't go higher and the down disabled when it can't go lower. So far when I've only added steps (and not removed) it works perfectly.
However when I delete a step, the `$index` somehow isn't updated in the `ng-disabled` altough it seems updated when I print it.

### Problem

Here's what I get after I delete the first step:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wz3qC.jpg)
As you can see, the down array is disabled. Although the printed index is 0, the index in the `ng-disabled` must still be 1.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-2 nopadding">
    <div class="btn-group btn-lg" role="group">
        <!--move step up-->
        <button type="button" class="btn iconbutton  " ng-click="" ng-disabled="{{$index}}==0"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></span> 
        </button>
        <!--move step down-->
        <button type="button" class="btn iconbutton " ng-click="" ng-disabled="{{$index}}==normal.length-1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></span> 
        </button>
        <!--remove step-->
        <button type="button" class="btn iconbutton " ng-click="removeStep(step,'normal',0)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span> 
        </button>
    </div>
    <p>index={{$index}}, length= {{normal.length}}</p>
</div>
```

remove function in the controller:

```
$scope.removeStep = function (item,flow,index) {
   if(angular.equals(flow,'normal')){
        var i = $scope.normal.indexOf(item);
        $scope.normal.splice(i, 1); 

   }
   if(angular.equals(flow,'alternative')){
        var i = $scope.alternative[index].behavior.indexOf(item);
        $scope.alternative[index].behavior.splice(i, 1); 


   }
   if(angular.equals(flow,'exceptional')){
        var i = $scope.exceptional[index].behavior.indexOf(item);
        $scope.exceptional[index].behavior.splice(i, 1); 
   }
```

};

### Update: found a work-around

It's not as clean as working with $index, but I wrote a function in my controller which, given the item, returns the position of that item in the array. This works for all situations

Comment: It looks like `index` is doing two different things, 1. as an argument to your function and 2. as a result of looking up your item. Which one is the correct interpretation?

Comment: @KristofferSall-Storgaard oh yes, you're right, that's obviously a mistake. Index should be the argument for my function and nothing more. I'll update the code. This doesn't solve my problem however

Answer (score 5):

user track by $index

```
ng-repeat="i in items track by $index"
```

when you will delete an element from an array,the array elements will be re indexed and angular will remove the associated dom element.But it will not re render the view using new indexed array. That's why the value of $index will not change after deleting an element from the array.If you use track by $index then angular will keep track the $index also and update its value accordingly.

Comment: Explain why this is a correct answer, else it will be deleted.

Comment: @BlackJack Could you please review the answer
$index will change 
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GEYXWTHF7KKZ

Answer (score 0):

as per ng-repeat documentation in https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat you can identify first and last ng-repeat iterations by using the ng-repeat scope specific $first and $last scope variables so rather than using ng-disabled="{{$index}}==0" for up arrow, you could use ng-disabled="{{$first}}".

That would be my first try at the problem without full source to test it out.

Comment: I didn't know $first and $last existed. I used ng-disabled={{$first}} and ng-disabled={{$last}} and without deleting, only the up arrow is disabled correctly. The down arrow remains disabled even if its value becomes false.